# Sound Icon not appearing

Tags: 11.04, sound, icons, system, youtube

I'm using 11.04 LTS. Everything is going fine. But the other day I booted up and went to use Youtube. I went to adjust the volume but the icon has gone, and the only way to adjust it is to either:

Use my Fn key + F6, F5 and F3.

Go to System - Preferences - Sound

Please help. I don't like these ways to set my volume.

Comment: There is a typo in your question. When you say "11.04 LTS", is it "12.04 LTS" or just "11.04" ?

Comment: Just 11.04. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the dconf Editor. Then, go to `com` > `canonical` > `indicator` > `sound` (tree at the left of the window). After that, ensure that the checkbox corresponding to `visible` is checked to see the sound indicator.